# Regex: replace all characters after 15th with '...'

Tags: regex

I am trying to do some simple formatting stuff with 'sed' in linux, and i need to use a regex to trim a string after the 15th character, and append a '...' to the end. Something like this:

```
before: this is a long string that needs to be shortened
after: this is a long ...
```

Can anyone please show me how i could write this as a regex, and if possible explain how it works so that i might learn regex a little better?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
echo "This is a test with more than 15 characters" | sed "s/\(.\{15\}\).\+$/\1…/"
```

What happens here is that we match any character ( `.`) 15 times (`{15}`). We capture the text so matched inside parentheses. The following part (`.+$`) matches all the rest, until the end of the line. We replace this by whatever we've captured inside the parentheses (`\1`), followed by the hyperbolic ellipsis.

To satisfy `sed`'s regex dialect (BRE) we have to escape some of the characters.

Comment: Should probably make that .+ instead of .*, so that it doesn't match a string of exactly 15 characters.

Answer (score 6):

Explanation of Konrand Rudolph's answer, since you requested explanations (ah, as I wrote this, Konrad added his own explanation too!)

```
 sed "s/\(.\{15\}\).+$/\1…/"

\(
```

start a group - ask the regexp engine to remember what's inside the parens, and assign the first such group to \1, the second to \2 etc. We will only need \1  here

```
.
```

Match anything...

```
\{15\}
```

... 15 times.

```
\)
```

end the group. So \1 will contain the first 15 characters

```
 .+
```

match anything again. The + means "one or more times",so will match characters beyond the 15 characters we matched above,...

```
 $
```

...until the end of the line

Now for the replace bit:

```
\1
```

Replace with the contents of \1

```
...
```

and three dots.

Done!

Comment: Typo: You write \} when you mean \\) to end the group.

Comment: I hadn't noticed that an explanation was requested and thought the author just needed a way around BRE's quirks.

Answer (score 2):

With Perl regular expressions:

```
$ echo 'this is a long string that needs to be shortened' \
| perl -pe 's/^(.{15}).+/$1.../'
this is a long ...
```

The easiest way to think about regular expressions is to consider it a pattern that needs to be matched.  In this case the pattern begins with the beginning of the line:

```
^
```

(Note that `/` is an arbitrary separator.  Other characters could be used instead.)  The `^` is the symbol that represents the start of the line in a regex.  Next the regex matches any character:

```
^.
```

A `.` is the regex symbol for any character.  But we want to match the first 15 characters:

```
^.{15}
```

There are several different modifiers that represent a repetition.  The most common is `*` which signifies 0 or more.  A `+` indicates 1 or more.  `{15}` obviously represents exactly 15.  (The `{...}` notations is more general.  So `*` could be written `{0,}` and `+` is the same as `{1,}`.)  Now we need to capture the first 15 characters so that we can use them later:

```
^(.{15})
```

Everything between `(` and `)` is captured and placed in a special variable called `$1` (or sometimes `\1`).  The second chunk captured would be placed in `$2` and so on.  Finally, you need to match to the end of the line so that you can throw that part away:

```
^(.{15}).+
```

I initially used `*`, but as another person pointed out, that probably isn't what is wanted when the string is exactly 15 characters long:

```
$ echo 'this is a long ' \
| perl -pe 's/^(.{15}).*/$1.../'
this is a long ...
```

Using a `+` means the pattern will not match if there is not a 16<sup>th</sup> character to replace.

The second half of the statement is what gets printed:

```
$1...
```

The `$1` variable that we caught earlier is used and the dots are literal `.`s on this side of the substitution.  Generally, everything except regex variables are literal on the right side of a substitution statement.

Answer (score 0):

In perl, you could write `s/(.{15}).*/$1.../`.  I'm not sure sed can use the {15} notation but if not, `s/\(...............\).*/\1.../` (with 15 dots in the group).

I can never remember whether you need to escape `(` when grouping in sed.  I just tried it and you do need `\(` and `\)`

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want to just whack off everything after the 15th character, or are you trying to impose a 15-character maximum length?  What if the string is 16 characters long?  All of the solutions presented so far will chop off that one excess character only to replace it with *three* dots. (I know Konrad and Paul used the ellipsis character, but the OP used three dots in the example; we should get a ruling on that.)

If you want to trim the strings to a maximum length of 15 *including the three dots*, you can do this:

```
s/^\(.\{12\}\).\{3\}.\+$/\1.../
```

It still only matches if there are more than 15 characters, but then it chops off everything after the 12th character to make room for the dots.